# Django syndication: How do I avoid description escaping?

Tags: django, django-rss, django-syndication

I'm trying to make a webcomic RSS feed with Django, but I can't put an image in the description field, because the html code gets escaped, even if it's in an {% autoescape off %} block.

Here is my description template:

```
{% autoescape off %}
<img src="{{obj.img.url}}"/>
{% endautoescape %}
```

And this is the result:

```
&lt;img src="http://localhost:8000/media/comics/001__.png"/&gt;
```

How can I avoid this autoescaping?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How can I avoid this autoescaping?

Actually, you need to keep this auto-escaping... Look carefully at any other rss feeds: [xkcd.com/rss.xml](http://xkcd.com/rss.xml)

[Quote from spec](http://www.rssboard.org/rss-specification#hrelementsOfLtitemgt) by the RSS Advisory Board:

> A channel may contain any number of
>   items. An item may represent a
>   "story" -- much like a story in a
>   newspaper or magazine; if so its
>   description is a synopsis of the
>   story, and the link points to the full
>   story. An item may also be complete in
>   itself, if so, the description
>   contains the text (**entity-encoded HTML
>   is allowed**; [see examples](http://www.rssboard.org/rss-encoding-examples)), and the
>   link and title may be omitted. All
>   elements of an item are optional,
>   however at least one of title or
>   description must be present.

http://www.rssboard.org/rss-encoding-examples

Comment: As internet evolves in recent 5 years, your example are out of the date now.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to have anything to do with autoescaping, as that would never 'escape' the hard-coded tags that you entered explicitly in your template as you have here.

I suspect there's something further down the line that is doing the escaping. Can you post the code that renders the template and does something with the result?